# ethers.js - How to get logs of "transfert" events emitted by ERC20 contracts for a specific wallet?

Tags: ethers.js

I am looking for a way to **get history** `Transfer` **events for  (from & to) a specific wallet emitted from any contract**. Maybe using the topics filter of `provider.getLogs(filter)`.

Using the `contract.filters.Transfer(myAddress)` allows to get logs only for 1 specific contract.

[Ethers documentation about events](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/concepts/events/#events)